# Is there a way to use semantic linefeeds in markdown tables?

Tags: html-table, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I would like to use [semantic](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/one-sentence-per-line/) [linefeeds](https://sembr.org) when writing tables markdown such that each cell can appear on its own line.

For example, if I have this table:

```
|         | Column One | Column Two | Column Three |
|---------|------------|------------|--------------|
| Row One | Cell One   | Cell Two   | Cell Three   |
| Row Two | Cell Four  | Cell Five  | Cell Six     |
```

Assuming that each cell's content might be a full sentence, I might want to write it something like this:

```
|         | Column One | Column Two | Column Three |
|---------|------------|------------|--------------|
| Row One
  | Cell One
  | Cell Two
  | Cell Three
| Row Two
  | Cell Four
  | Cell Five
  | Cell Six
```

Is there any way in GitHub Flavored Markdown to break the cells of a single row across multiple lines, outside of just writing the raw HTML tags?

Comment: Upon further reflection, I believe what I am looking for is bash-style _line continuation_, and this question is effectively also duplicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955160/markdown-table-with-long-lines

Answer (score 0):

Neat idea, but unfortunately this isn't supported by [GitHub's support for tables in Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-).