# How to break lines for source formatting only

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I need to generate a markdown table like such:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Very long description here: wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd |

```markdown
|||
|---|---|
|1|Very long description here: wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd wasd |
```

I want to break the "Very long description line" for source formatting purposes only, so that I don't have a very very very very very long line in my IDE. However, if I break the line, the MD processor interprets it as a new table row. Is there an EOL escape that would allow me to break the source line but not the current MD block element?

Comment: Does the `<br>` tag work?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz It works like a charm, just not for what I asked for. I asked for breaking source code lines without impact on the output, not the other way around. I just want to keep the source code lines shorter. I want a line break in the source code that has no impact whatsoever on the output. I want to write each word on a new line, if you wish :)

Comment: Yea... so basically I have a source file where to represent a block of text in a table cell, I need to have a line 500 characters long. I'd like to keep lines to about 120 characters, because it's so awkward to make changes on a 500-characters line of text.

Comment: If it helps, a similar discussion went down here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955160/markdown-table-with-long-lines, but unfortunately, it looks like you have to resort to html `<table>`s.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable **line/word/soft wrapping** in your text editor.

You can enable it in VSCode by searching for `wrap` and turning it on:

[image]

Or under <kbd>Settings ➔ Editor ➔ Soft Wrap</kbd> in Atom.